# How to use moment js for displaying formatted date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Guys I am getting date through ajax call in my ASP.net mvc application. Now the date I am getting is in the format of `2014-06-09T17:38:55` however I want to display it in three formats:

1. Like this `06/09/2014 05:38:55 PM`
2. Like `three hours ago` or `Yesterday` style (used by facebook)
3. Just the date part like `06/09/2014`

Basically I have a hidden input field in my view which gets the Date from ajax call. Now I am doing something like this :

```
<input id="hiddenLastAlertDate" type="hidden" value="values.CreationDate" />
```

In my script section, I have a function in which I am doing something like this:

```
var datefield = document.getElementById("hiddenLastAlertDate").value;
formattedDate = moment(datefield).format('L'); //for getting the date part only
```

Upon running the application,formattedDate shows up as undefined. Why is that? I think I was unable to follow the moment.js documentation. How can I use moment.js to get this formatted result ?

Comment: Have you looked at http://momentjs.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am having trouble following the docs.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please share your code.

Comment: The frontpage shows you exactly how. Stick your date string into `moment()` to get a moment that represents your date and then call methods on that object. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bf6pw/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moment("20140618 08:00", "YYYYMMDD hh:mm").fromNow();` will return `2 hours ago`

`moment("20140617", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();` will return `a day ago`

`moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss A');` will return `18/06/2014 9:42:24 AM`

Comment: do I put my var `datefield` like this `moment("datefield", "YYYYMMDD hh:mm").fromNow();` ?

Comment: Try `moment("2014-06-09T17:38:55").fromNow()`